# Disappearing 3D texture with libgdx

Tags: android, opengl-es, libgdx

this is a bug that has been troubling and demotivating me for several days now. Perhaps someone has some insight.

I build a terrain mesh programmatically and set up a renderable for it, with a material that has a texture attribute with a repeating texture created from a PNG file. All of this appears to work fine until the camera is moved for a while, along, say, the x or z axes, at which time the texture will initially flicker to black, and eventually stay black, if the camera is moved far enough away.

I clear the screen with blue – so the mesh is still getting rendered, just without the texture – so it is solid black. This happens at the same spots with regards to camera placement. Once the camera is far enough away, the problem persists if the camera continues to move away from the world origin.

The problem does not appear on desktop, only android. I am using an HTC EVO 4G to test. I realize that this phone's early Adreno GPU has some serious 3D issues, but I've surely seen games, or at least demos, with large textured landscapes work fine. My mesh has around 5000 triangles and usually renders around 30-40 fps.

Some things I have experimented with:

- Change PNG compression to 0 in the GIMP export options
- Used JPG instead of PNG
- Explictly specifying no mipmapping
- Changed filtering modes
- PNG files of different sizes and resolutions
- Check glGetError

Here is the relevant code:

```
private void createMesh(){
    mesh = new Mesh(true, vertices.length, indices.length, 
                    new VertexAttribute(Usage.Position, 3, "a_position"),
                    new VertexAttribute(Usage.Normal, 3, "a_normal"),
                    new VertexAttribute(Usage.TextureCoordinates, 2, "a_texCoord0"));

    float vertexData[] = new float[vertices.length * 8];

    for (int x = 0; x < vertices.length; x++) {
      vertexData[x*8] = vertices[x].position.x;
      vertexData[x*8+1] = vertices[x].position.y;
      vertexData[x*8+2] = vertices[x].position.z;
      vertexData[x*8+3] = vertices[x].normal.x;
      vertexData[x*8+4] = vertices[x].normal.y;
      vertexData[x*8+5] = vertices[x].normal.z;
      vertexData[x*8+6] = vertices[x].texCoord.x;
      vertexData[x*8+7] = vertices[x].texCoord.y;

    }
    mesh.setVertices(vertexData);   
    mesh.setIndices(indices);
  }
```

The texture repeats across the terrain, but I've commented out the setWrap line before and the problem
persists.

```
private void createRenderable(Lights lights){
    texture.setWrap(TextureWrap.Repeat, TextureWrap.Repeat);
    TextureAttribute textureAttribute1 = new TextureAttribute(TextureAttribute.Diffuse, texture);
    terrain = new Renderable();
    terrain.mesh = mesh;
    terrain.worldTransform.trn(-xTerrainSize/2, (float) -heightRange, -zTerrainSize/2);
    terrain.meshPartOffset = 0;
    terrain.meshPartSize = mesh.getNumIndices(); 
    terrain.primitiveType = GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP; // or GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP etc.
    terrain.material = new Material(textureAttribute1);
    terrain.lights = lights;
  }
```

Note that decreasing the far clipping plane does not make a difference.

```
...
lights = new Lights();
        lights.ambientLight.set(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1f);
        lights.add(new DirectionalLight().set(0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f, -1f, -0.8f, -0.2f));

        cam = new PerspectiveCamera(90, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
        cam.position.set(0, 0, 0);
        cam.lookAt(0,0,-1);
        cam.near = 0.1f;
        cam.far = 1000f;
        cam.update();
...



 @Override
    public void render () {
        ...

        Gdx.gl.glViewport(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
        Gdx.graphics.getGL10().glClearColor( 0, 0, 1, 1 );
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        modelBatch.begin(cam);
        modelBatch.render(terrain);
        modelBatch.end();

      ...
    }
```

Any insight into this problem would be much-appreciated. Unfortunately, it is difficult to screen capture on an EVO 4G, or else I would post a picture.

Comment: Are you using OpenGL2.0 or 1.x?  How big is a "large" distance from the origin?

Comment: 1.x I use the default shader that libgdx provides. The model goes black at x:-131 y:-2 z:-8, for instance - so not too unreasonable, and if I continue to go back in the x direction, will remain totally black. Curiously, it doesn't seem to fail with a predictable radius around any origin, but more like it fails along a plane that bisects the scene. I have no explanation for this.